# Django + SQL Server + update_or_create = ERROR 23000

Tags: sql-server, django, pyodbc

Why does the following code give me an error when trying to write to a SQL Server but not on sqlite3 or mysql?

```py
obj, created = cls.objects.using(database_data).update_or_create(**item)
```

The datamodel is defined below:

```py
class fubar(models.Model)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='ABCD')
    market_participant = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='ACME')
    trade_date = models.DateField()
    interval_begin = models.DateTimeField()
    interval_end = models.DateTimeField()
    interval_type = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='5MIN')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=None, null=True, blank=True)
    location_type = models.CharField(max_length=32, default=None)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [
            'region',
            'market_participant',
            'trade_date',
            'interval_begin',
            'interval_end',
            'interval_type',
            'location',
            'location_type'
        ]
```

```py
IntegrityError: (
  '23000',
  "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
  Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.foo`
  with unique index 'foo_region_market_participant_trade_date_interval_begin_inte_d7d3bf7e_uniq'.
  The duplicate key value is
  (ABCD, ACME, 2020-12-06, 2020-12-06 00:00:00.0000000, 2020-12-06 00:05:00.0000000, 5MIN, BAZ, QUX).
  (2601)
  (SQLExecDirectW)"
)
```

Note: Error code was originally one line. I have re-formatted for readability.

Comment: maybe this will help: https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/issues/50

Comment: The problem there was a <null> I believe, when I googled and found more information relating to that issue. In this case, there is no null. It is certainly possible that the underlying issue is the same nonetheless.

Comment: It is, since you have null=True on location and for some reason a `unique_together` for all fields. If you have that constraint, your update_or_create must also select all fields, so by definition it's always an insert ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: That makes sense. How does one resolve this problem sensibly? Removing the null=True may not be an option. Should I try and hash the unique values before doing a update_or_create to compensate for the database idiosyncracy?